# skipping music on flash drive in my car

Tags: usb

I'm very frustrated with my music in my car. I've loaded over 400 songs on a 4 gb flash drive and have listened to my music for over 4 years and now many of the songs are starting skip throughout the entire playing of the song. In the interim I have deleted and added different songs but never this problem until recently.

Does the flash drive or the usb port in my car need cleaning and if so, how can that be done?

Please help

Comment: You’ve been using the same 4gb flash drive for over 4 years... Have you done anything to troubleshoot this problem? Tried a new flash drive? Tried the flash drive in a different car?

Answer (score 1):

Flash drives just do that after a time, even if only written once, then played back many.
Just bin it & get a new one, or try reformat & reload it.
Sometimes that will give you a bit more life, as it *may* map out some bad blocks.